# How to generate Segwit address using bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, segregated-witness

I am using bitcoind. It generates the BTC addresses(not segregated). How to get segwit addresses? Do I have to change the settings in `bitcoin.conf` file?

`bitcoin-cli getnewaddress`  -- generates address that starts with '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using Bitcoin-core v0.16 `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo` then in your bitcoin.conf add

```
addresstype=bech32
```

As @Meshcolider comment if you want to get p2sh address you should set:

```
addresstype=p2sh-segwit
```

But I would use bech32 since bech32 produces smaller transactions than P2SH segwit transactions.

---

For Bitcoin-core version 0.15 send

`bitcoin-cli addwitnessaddress 1BRo7qrYHMPrzdBDzfjmzteBdYAyTMXW75`

to get p2sh address.

Comment: After adding, when I use "getnewaddress" , will it give me a segwit address directly?

Comment: Yeah, nothing more required. You are most welcome!